# Ler descrição do Feed (rss) com PHP

Tags: php, xml, rss, feed

Estou tentando pegar a descrição do **feed** para exibir em um site que tenho que fazer, mas ao tentar pegar ele me retorna como vazio. Quando vejo o código fonte do link que está o feed, a descrição está lá:

```
<description><![CDATA[
    <div>
    <a href="http://eissomesmo.com.br/blog/e-dicas/"><img title="Eisso4" src="http://eissomesmo.com.br/blog/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/Eisso4.jpg" alt="É Dicas!" width="230"  height="230" /></a>
    </div>
    Para um conteúdo cumprir a sua função, deve ser feito adaptado para ser exibido em várias plataformas de mídia e pensado estrategicamente para atrair a atenção do público-alvo e mantê-lo. Este conteúdo pode assumir diversas formas como notícias, videos instrutivos, e-books, posts de blog, guias, artigos, perguntas e respostas, imagens, entre outros. Empresas que constroem]]></description>
```

Mas o PHP me retorna vazio quando puxo a tag `description`. Estou usando esse código:

```
$curl_handle=curl_init();
        curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL,'http://eissomesmo.com.br/blog/feed/');
        curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 2);
        curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'rss');
        $query = curl_exec($curl_handle);
        curl_close($curl_handle);

        $rss = new SimpleXmlElement($query);

        echo '<pre>';
        echo var_dump($rss->channel->item->description);
        echo '</pre>';
```

O Feed está sendo gerado pelo Wordpress. Link para o feed é http://eissomesmo.com.br/blog/feed/

Answer (score 1):

Bem isso ocorre porque dentro do XML algumas tags contem os comandos **CDATA**, que como sabemos ele serve para passar valores que não devem ser interpretado pelo XML e sim como os próprios valores, nesse seu caso ele serve para o XML não ser confundido com HTML pois eles contem < & > ...

> <![CDATA[ ... ]]>

O problema é que o PHP e suas bibliotecas que lidam com XML tem um bug que não consegue interpretar corretamente o CDATA, segundo alguns fóruns includido o SOF *(em inglês)* se você atualizar suas libs XML talvez funciona corretamente esse problema.

Porem se não quiser atualizar um jeito de se fazer isso é forcar o PHP a  fundir os CDATA com o texto usando o argumento [LIBXML_NOCDATA](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/libxml.constants.php) dentro da função [simplexml_load_string](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.simplexml-load-string.php) na hora da leitura por exemplo.

```
<?php
$curl_handle = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL, "http://eissomesmo.com.br/blog/feed/");
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 2);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "rss");
$query = curl_exec($curl_handle);
curl_close($curl_handle);

$rss = simplexml_load_string($query, "SimpleXMLElement", LIBXML_NOCDATA);
$desc = $rss->channel->item->description;

preg_match('/<a href=\"([^\"]*)\"><[^>]*?src="([^"]+)"[^>]*><\/a>/isU', $rss->channel->item->description, $valores);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($valores);
echo "</pre>";
?>
```

**EDIT:** Conforme a pergunta do colega feita via comentario, estou adicionando uma [Expressão Regular](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Express%C3%A3o_regular) que extrai os dados que estão dentro da `div` com a ajuda da função [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) retornando numa matriz tipo essa:

```
 Array (
  [0] => <a href="http://eissomesmo.com.br/blog/e-pascoa-2/"><img title="post_relacionamento_3" src="http://eissomesmo.com.br/blog/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/post_relacionamento_3.jpg" alt="É Páscoa!" width="230"  height="220" /></a>
  [1] => http://eissomesmo.com.br/blog/e-pascoa-2/
  [2] => http://eissomesmo.com.br/blog/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/post_relacionamento_3.jpg
)
```

*Nós meus testes essa solução deu certo, mas como não sei a versão do seu PHP precisa testar.*

Comment: deu certo, apenas exibiu algo a mais, que foi o conteúdo da `<div></div>` que eu não preciso, pois a imagem já peguei de uma outra forma. Você saberia como retirar o conteúdo que está entre a tag `<div>` ?

Comment: @Alisson Acioli bem isso não estava na sua pergunta inicial, você só estava dizendo que o valor vinha vazio :P, porém com um ER eu leio os dados internos e retorno numa matriz, espero que seja isso.